# Tomcat won't start even with both JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME set

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-tomee, java-home

I have to install tomEE to run an application I have to modify. 
But when I use

```
\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\bin>start startup.bat
```

I get the following message :

"Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined
At least one of these environment variable is needed to run this program"

The problem is I have already set my two variables :

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102
```

for JAVA_HOME

and

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102
```

By the way I already set CATALINA_HOME to me apache folder

All suggestions are welcome :)

Best regards.

Comment: Just for verification, can you try typing "echo %JAVA_HOME%" in a CMD window?

Comment: Do you use enclose value in ""  when set variable?

Comment: You have already set them how?

Comment: @YoavGur I get this result : %JAVA_HOME% instead of the location

Comment: @EJP I set them through windows' system advanced parameters

Comment: @Antoine, is your JAVA_HOME environment variable added to PATH environment variable too?

Comment: I had exactly the same behavior you had when using the Windows Power Shell to start Tomcat by executing the startup.bat - including the result of the echo command.

After switching to the cmd-shell, Tomcat started fine.